# Searching for parks in one or more state

Tags: javascript, api, endpoint

Im a new developer looking for help from someone with more experience. I'm trying to understand how to use a api/endpoint I created a key and now im trying to get my app to search for parks in one or more states and also display the full name, the description. Here's the api documentation. I hope I asked the question well enough I'm open to constructive criticism.

API (please copy and paste link in a new tab)
https://www.nps.gov/subjects/developer/api-documentation.htm#/parks/getPark

```js
'use strict';

// put your own value below!
const apiKey = ''; 
const searchURL = 'https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?parkCode=acad&';


function formatQueryParams(params) {
  const queryItems = Object.keys(params)
    .map(key => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(params[key])}`)
  return queryItems.join('&');
}

function displayResults(responseJson) {
  // if there are previous results, remove them
  console.log(responseJson);
  $('#results-list').empty();
  // iterate through the items array
  for (let i = 0; i < responseJson.items.length; i++){
    // for each video object in the items 
    //array, add a list item to the results 
    //list with the video title, description,
    //and thumbnail
    $('#results-list').append(
      `<li><h3>${responseJson.items[i].snippet.title}</h3>
      <p>${responseJson.items[i].snippet.description}</p>
      <img src='${responseJson.items[i].snippet.thumbnails.default.url}'>
      </li>`
    )};
  //display the results section  
  $('#results').removeClass('hidden');
};

function getYouTubeVideos(query, maxResults=10) {
  const params = {
    key: apiKey,
    q: query,
    part: 'snippet',
    maxResults,
    type: 'video'
  };
  const queryString = formatQueryParams(params)
  const url = searchURL + '?' + queryString;

  console.log(url);

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    })
    .then(responseJson => displayResults(responseJson))
    .catch(err => {
      $('#js-error-message').text(`Something went wrong: ${err.message}`);
    });
}

function watchForm() {
  $('form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const searchTerm = $('#js-search-term').val();
    const maxResults = $('#js-max-results').val();
    getYouTubeVideos(searchTerm, maxResults);
  });
}

$(watchForm);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

button, input[type="text"] {
  padding: 5px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.error-message {
    color: red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>YouTube video finder</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Park finder</h1>

        <form id="js-form">
            <label for="search-term">Search term</label>
            <input type="text" name="search-term" id="js-search-term" required>

            <label for="max-results">Maximum results to return</label>
            <input type="number" name="max-results" id="js-max-results" value="10">

            <input type="submit" value="Go!">
        </form>

        <p id="js-error-message" class="error-message"></p>
        <section id="results" class="hidden">
          <h2>Search results</h2>
          <ul id="results-list">
          </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
'use strict';

// put your own value below!
const apiKey = 'XDkrghHigMG7xYtlfMloyKAoJ04H4te9h3UKWW3g'; 
const searchURL = 'https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?parkCode=acad&api_key=XDkrghHigMG7xYtlfMloyKAoJ04H4te9h3UKWW3g';


function formatQueryParams(params) {
  const queryItems = Object.keys(params)
    .map(key => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(params[key])}`)
  return queryItems.join('&');
}

function displayResults(responseJson) {
  // if there are previous results, remove them
  console.log(responseJson);
  $('#results-list').empty();
  // iterate through the items array
  for (let i = 0; i < responseJson.items.length; i++){
    // for each video object in the items 
    //array, add a list item to the results 
    //list with the video title, description,
    //and thumbnail
    $('#results-list').append(
      `<li><h3>${responseJson.items[i].snippet.title}</h3>
      <p>${responseJson.items[i].snippet.description}</p>
      <img src='${responseJson.items[i].snippet.thumbnails.default.url}'>
      </li>`
    )};
  //display the results section  
  $('#results').removeClass('hidden');
};

function getYouTubeVideos(query, maxResults=10) {
  const params = {
    key: apiKey,
    q: query,
    part: 'snippet',
    maxResults,
    type: 'video'
  };
  const queryString = formatQueryParams(params)
  const url = searchURL + '?' + queryString;

  console.log(url);

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      (responseJson => displayResults(responseJson))
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
        console.log(response.json());
      }
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      $('#js-error-message').text(`Something went wrong: ${err.message}`);
    });
}

function watchForm() {
  $('form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const searchTerm = $('#js-search-term').val();
    const maxResults = $('#js-max-results').val();
    getYouTubeVideos(searchTerm, maxResults);
  });
}

$(watchForm);
```

Comment: Could you tell us what kind of error you are receiving when you try to run your code? Or what exactly you need clarificatoin on? Also when you call your function at the end it should be `watchForm();`

Comment: when I run it I only get the url and my api in the console. For the most part I need help getting my app to search for parks

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few things going on and I have some debug suggestions. Also, I would recommend cleaning up the Javascript so that it doesn't have a YouTube reference...

When you fetch(url) the first .then returns the json result but your call of the function doesn't do anything with the result. Presumably you would call displayResults, but you're not doing that (yet?). So at least console log response.json to see what's happening

You're use of two . then is incorrect. The first returns from the function so the second is never called. Get rid of the then and move the code into the first then

Debug suggestions - when you're stuck on something it's best to break it down into small steps and check the behavior from beginning to end

- did you generate the right query url? You have console logged it which is good. Copy the url and paste into browser. Are you getting good json back? If not, go through the url building process step by step. Which reminds me, make sure you use your api key, it's set to "" in your code
- check that your code is returning the same json as you got from the browser, if not, check whether anything is different between the browser call and the fetch
- this should have got you past the point where you are stuck. Next step is to check the display function, and so on

Comment: I updated the js above with the recommendations you gave but im only getting back the url and the api in the console. Can you tell me where im going wrong.

Comment: Your code after fetch is still a little confused. The callback function is called with "response" as the argument. You then define another function with responseJson as the input parameter, so you're still not picking up the returned results. Console log `response` before doing anything else, get rid of the second function and the `return()` statement, then call call displayResults. In displayResults() you will have to convert the json to a Javascript object (array of objects). Did you test out the url in a browser ?